# UIButton's image and title edge insets programmatically in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, uiedgeinsets

I am setting two UIButtons programmatically which look like this:

[image]

I am trying to set the image and text insets to be the same in buttons, but somehow left button's image is located differently than the right one.
I have this extension to UIButton class:

```
func setTextAndImageForButton(spacing: CGFloat) {
        let insetAmount = spacing / 2
        imageEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 8, left: 4, bottom: 8, right: insetAmount)
        titleEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 4, bottom: 0, right: -insetAmount)
        contentEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: insetAmount, left: 0, bottom: insetAmount, right: insetAmount*1.5)
    }
```

As far as I understand when I set the insets for image, text and whole content, it should be located in the same place for both instances.

Are the insets override somehow after I set them in code?

Comment: May be image inset is changed with your title length.

Comment: [contentHorizontalAlignment](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uicontrol/1618213-contenthorizontalalignment)

Comment: OK, when I set 'contentHorizontalAlignment = .left' it is moved to the left as expected. In documentation there is written that "The default value of this property is left." so I am wondering why it was centered by default.
Is there a way to have UIButton's icon aligned to left and in the same time UIButton's title centered without making new class for it?

Comment: Share your screenshort.

Comment: You can try how insets behave for different settings using this app https://github.com/tomas789/UIButtonEdgeInsets